# Why isn't pip or easy_install working?

Tags: python, pip, tweepy, easy-install, six

I'm trying to make something using the API tweepy and it says:

```
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

When I try to install 'six' with pip or easy_install using the cmd, I get this error message:

```
'easy_install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7

Comment: For clarity add pip version you were talking about. EoR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add easy_install/pip to the system path (assuming that you use Windows). These execs are usually located in: C:\Python27\Scripts. If they are not there you need to install them. Refer to these tips for pip: [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

when you downloaded it there is a box saying Add variable to path or something like that so go to the installer uninstall then check the box[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yrmT.png)

Comment: Their is other ways to do this but this is the simplest

Comment: and this would require you to reinstall python so tbh i dont recommend